# Bug in Mathematica 9 (Quaternion)

Tags: bugs, quaternions

The code:

```
<< Quaternions`;
Exp[Quaternion[1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

produces an error:

```
During evaluation of In[81]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>

During evaluation of In[81]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>

During evaluation of In[81]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>

During evaluation of In[81]:= General::stop: Further output of Power::infy will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

During evaluation of In[81]:= $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>

During evaluation of In[81]:= $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>

During evaluation of In[81]:= $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>

During evaluation of In[81]:= General::stop: Further output of $RecursionLimit::reclim will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

During evaluation of In[81]:= $IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded. >>

During evaluation of In[81]:= Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered. >>
```

I expect it to output `E` instead.

Quaternion exponent formula is

```
In[84]:= ScalarQ[x_] = True;
Exp[Quaternion[a, b, c, d]]

Out[85]= Quaternion[E^a Cos[Sqrt[b^2 + c^2 + d^2]], (
 b E^a Sin[Sqrt[b^2 + c^2 + d^2]])/Sqrt[b^2 + c^2 + d^2], (
 c E^a Sin[Sqrt[b^2 + c^2 + d^2]])/Sqrt[b^2 + c^2 + d^2], (
 d E^a Sin[Sqrt[b^2 + c^2 + d^2]])/Sqrt[b^2 + c^2 + d^2]]
```

but quaternion cannot substitute directly in case `AbsIJK[x] == 0`.

Is there a fix in *Mathematica* 10? Is there any reason for it to cause error?

Comment: It still present in 10.x.

Comment: Version 5.2 (the version before the add-on packages were completely overhauled) does not have a problem evaluating `Exp[Quaternion[1, 0, 0, 0]]`. I suspect something done during the transition to version 6 broke it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### An attempt to fix

Go to Mathematica installation path, find the `Quaternion.m` package file.
In line 359, you should find the original definition:

```
Quaternion /:
Sign[a:Quaternion[__?ScalarQ]]:= a / Abs[a]
```

change the definition to this:

```
Quaternion /:
Sign[a:Quaternion[__?ScalarQ]]:= If[Abs[a]==0, 0, a / Abs[a]]
```

### My investigations

First I used `TracePrint` on Mathematica 10.4.1, and found something like `Quaternion[0, 0, 0, 0]/Abs[Quaternion[0, 0, 0, 0]]` appears before the error messages, and `Sign` function was simply defined as `a/Abs[a]`, that's why I changed that function.

J.M. mentioned that in 5.2 this can return a result. I tested it and also found it true. But when I see the trace print, I found `AdjustedSignIJK` runs into a case where it commented: `(* This seems very wrong. *)`, and returns `I` for sign. However in the following calculations, a `0` from other place multiples with this `I`, so accidentally it becomes correct. In 6.0, the package was modified. From line 387 to 390:

```
(* fix bug 66775 -- charlesp *)

SignIJK[Quaternion[a_?ScalarQ, b_?ScalarQ, c_?ScalarQ, d_?ScalarQ]] :=
Sign[Quaternion[0, b, c, d]]
```

Looks like an attempt to fix this bug(at least it doesn't run into that case anymore), that's where it made the program calls `Sign`. Since `Sign` did not consider case `0`, the new bug happened.

This is only my shallow observation. I am not sure if this can break anything else.